# strange error with form submit.button in dutch oke but english not working

Tags: javascript, forms

i have a strange problem with my form. I have a register.php page that in dutch language works (called aanmelden.html) but when you click the english button  does not work (called register.html) anymore, and when i compare them i don't see any big differens.

also on the same page the login is same problem. 
could anyone give my a hint where to look.

```
<form class="inline" id="loginform" name="loginform" action="=REGISTERPAGE.html" method="post">
    <p><label for="loginusername">username</label>
    <input id="loginusername" name="loginusername" class="required" /></p>
                                    <p>
    <label for="loginpassword">password</label>
    <input id="loginpassword" name="loginpassword"  class="required" type="password" />
                        </p>
                    <p>
    <label for="keeploggedin">keeploggedin</label>
    <input id="keeploggedin" name="keeploggedin" type="checkbox" />     </p>
                                    <p>
    <span class="sprite button submit" id="login_submit_button">login</span>
                            </p>                        </fieldset>
                </form>
```

The script that submits the form is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

```
$("#login_submit_button").click(function()
{
    if($("#loginform").valid())
    {
        $("#loginform").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This `action="=REGISTERPAGE.html"` should (probably) be `action="REGISTERPAGE.html"`

Comment: @BillyMoon, indeed, just barely passed you (~22s) :D

Comment: How do you find out the time that accurately?

Comment: @BillyMoon If the submission time is <1min, it says `answered N seconds ago`. When your answer came through the pipe and I clicked on "One new answer", I saw that yours was submitted ~4seconds ago, and mine ~26. I then took the difference, and there ya go!

Comment: After I submitted mine, it told me yours was submitted 8 seconds ago. Funny discrepancy. I wonder if there is a way to see the actual times. Maybe by querying the database - I saw something like that in stack apps once I think - somewhere you could query the database directly.

Comment: @BillyMoon: It is also possible my internet is causing some discrepancy, I'm at the Great Lakes Software Symposium in Chicago, and the hotel's wifi is struggling quite a bit!

Comment: struggle as it might, I am pretty sure it beats my Ethiopian EVDO connection hands down :)

Comment: Turns out query-able data is updated monthly, so we can find out next month. I am curious if there is a way, seems like an obvious thing to want to do...

Comment: @BillyMoon you can hover over timestamps associated with comments/answers/questions to get a complete timestamp including seconds. :-)

Comment: @Gijs that is much better than waiting a month to run a query on the stack overflow database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typo...

```
action="=REGISTERPAGE.html"
```

Should read...

```
action="REGISTERPAGE.html"
```

(I expect)